# Laravel database images update failue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to update images in my database.I am using laravel 5.4 version.
I am getting this error.

*Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::make() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_eshopper\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 1357*

Here is my update function in the controller script.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if use http://image.intervention.io/

Change `Product::make($image)` to `Image::make($image)`

Comment: Please provide some explanation to why you think above change will resolve the issue. That will help to understand the cause of the problem  and hence avoid the same mistake in future.

Answer (score 0):

Ah okay I know the problem.
First, the best practice is not save the image in database just save the path where you save the image.

Here I give you example code:

```php
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = public_path('images/home/');

    // now saving the file
    $image->move($location, $filename);

    // delete oldfile
    $oldFilaname = $product->image;
    Storage::delete($oldFilename);

    // update
    $product->image = $location . '/' . $filename;

}
```